# How to limit the number of orders per customer via a time limit in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to prevent selling each 24 hour by a customer.

> check if there are other purchases from that costumer at the past 24hr and display an error before payment and ask to return later

What I have tried so far

```php
function prevent_repeat_order() { 
    $last_24_hours_from_order_results = wc_get_customer_last_order($user_id);
    (array( 'date_created' => '>=' . (time() - 86400), // time in seconds 'paginate' => true // adds a total field to the results ));

    if ( $last_24_hours_from_last_order->total > 1 ) { 
        wc_add_notice('Too many orders in the last 24 hours. Please return later.', 'error');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'prevent_repeat_order', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course it depends on where you want to show the message. The following code shows a error message on the checkout page, and hides the *`proceed_to_checkout`* button if the condition is not met.

[image]

---

> With https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php 
>   the seconds can be converted to hours, etc...

```php
function new_order_allowed() {
    // Only on cart and check out pages
    if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) return;

    // Will only work for logged in users
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Get user id
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        // Get last order
        $last_order = wc_get_customer_last_order( $user_id );

        if ( $last_order ) {
            // Get date last order created - Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)
            $date_created = $last_order->get_date_created()->format( 'U' );

            // Get current date - Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)
            $current_time = current_time( 'U', true );

            // 24hr in seconds
            $day_in_sec = 60 * 60 * 24;

            // Seconds have passed since the last order
            $seconds_passed = $current_time - $date_created;

            // Check
            if ( $seconds_passed < $day_in_sec ) {
                // Add notice
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'New orders are only allowed %1$s seconds after your previous order, currently %2$s seconds are passed', $day_in_sec, $seconds_passed ), 'error' );

                // Removing the Proceed to checkout button from the Cart page
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout','woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'new_order_allowed' );
```